# Properties of Limits dealing with Existing and Not Existing

Tags: calculus, limits

If a function f(x) with limit (a) exists, but a function g(x) with limit (a) does not exist, does lim x->a f(x) + g(x) exist? f(x)* g(x)? f(x)/g(x)?

My thinking here is that f(x) + g(x) will still exists, as f(x) is an existing limit; however f(x) is unaffected by adding something that does not exist-like f(x) + 0. By this reasoning, I am considering g(x) for all of these as a property of 0. Is this a correct way of thinking?

Answer (score 2):

No, 0 and "undefined" are *extremely* different. In general, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists but $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$ does not, none of the three limits you consider need exist. Indeed, the first one will *never* exist, and the second two will only exist if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ equals something specific (exercise: find out what I mean by this).

When reasoning about limits, it's always best to *look at examples*. I recommend you look at a number of examples before trying to guess general priciples.

Comment: I did find that f(x) + g(x) equals an existing limit only if both exist, as a property. However, I could not find a definitive answer for multiplying or dividing by them.

Comment: @Diego27865 Your first sentence is at odds with what you write in the question ("My thinking here is that $f(x)+g(x)$ will still exists, as $f(x)$ is an existing limit"). If I'm misreading that, can you clarify? As to the other parts of your question, I **strongly** suggest you look at some specific examples.

Comment: I had figured it out. My thinking was wrong and I realized this when I found the property concerning adding two functions.